# Understanding the UIPickerView

Tags: iphone, xamarin.ios

I haven't been successful in finding any good examples that can walk me through understanding the UIPickerView and UIPickerViewModel. Any advice?

Comment: http://www.amazon.com/Beginning-iPhone-Development-Exploring-SDK/dp/1430224592 - Chapter 7 . Its about Tab Bars and Pickers and has some good examples to start with.

Comment: I'm trying to find a solution that does not include buying a book, but rather some form of online reference, blog entry, code sample, etc. The books I've seen to date all seem to only cursorily cover topics and move on, with no opportunity to discuss and followup on the topic.

Comment: I thought, you just need an introduction of those, with good simple examples, which are well explained in the book. Sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's an example in the MonoTouch samples: https://github.com/xamarin/monotouch-samples/tree/master/MonoCatalog-MonoDevelop

Answer (score 1):

Why not use default Apple doc example?  THere's example from apple doc called UICatalog.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/UICatalog/Listings/PickerViewController_h.html

Here it shows example of UIPickerView.